# Unexpected behaviour unit test in Streams (Dart)

Tags: unit-testing, dart, stream, mockito

I'm using two libraries to make streams: the native and getX. I created two groups for tests: the native and getX with same contract from an abstract class (`AnyPresenter`). One of them is `Stream<bool> get isLoadingStream` which for the native is `_state.isLoading` and for getx is `isLoading`.

The Streams only change when run the method below:

Native:

[image]

Getx:

[image]

I'm using the same test for both, but it is not running correctly in the native test.

Expect result:
[true, false]

Native error:
[image]

This is the sample code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

class AnyState {
  bool isLoading = false;
}

abstract class AnyPresenter {
  Stream<bool> get isLoadingStream;

  void doSomething();
}

class StreamAnyPresenter implements AnyPresenter {
  final AnyLibrary anyLibrary;

  var _controller = StreamController<AnyState>.broadcast();
  var _anyState = AnyState();

  StreamAnyPresenter(this.anyLibrary);

  Stream<bool> get isLoadingStream =>
      _controller.stream.map((anyState) => anyState.isLoading).distinct();

  Future<void> doSomething() async {
    _anyState.isLoading = true;
    _controller.add(_anyState);
    _anyState.isLoading = false;
    _controller.add(_anyState);
  }
}

class GetXPresenter implements AnyPresenter {
  final AnyLibrary anyLibrary;

  var isLoading = false.obs;

  GetXPresenter(this.anyLibrary);

  Stream<bool> get isLoadingStream => isLoading.stream.distinct();

  Future<void> doSomething() async {
    isLoading.value = true;
    isLoading.value = false;
  }
}

abstract class AnyLibrary {
  Future<void> someMethod();
}

class AnyLibrarySpy extends Mock implements AnyLibrary {}

void main() {
  AnyLibrarySpy anyLibrary;
  setUp(() {
    anyLibrary = AnyLibrarySpy();
  });

  group('Using native Stream', () {
    StreamAnyPresenter sut;

    setUp(() {
      sut = StreamAnyPresenter(anyLibrary);
    });

    test('Should emit events on Success', () async {
      expectLater(sut.isLoadingStream, emitsInOrder([true, false]));

      await sut.doSomething();
    });
  });

  group('Using getX', () {
    GetXPresenter sut;

    setUp(() {
      sut = GetXPresenter(anyLibrary);
    });

    test('Should emit events on Success', () async {
      expectLater(sut.isLoadingStream, emitsInOrder([true, false]));

      await sut.doSomething();
    });
  });
}
```

Sorry for any mistakes. English is not my native language

Comment: Try making the controller synchronous: `var _controller = StreamController<AnyState>.broadcast(sync: true);`. Your code is setting `_anyState.isLoading`, then scheduling an *asynchronous* event to deliver the `_anyState` object, and then you change `_anyState.isLoading` again before that event has been delivered.

Comment: It's works. I saw in the documentation that the use of sync as true should be used with cautious, because maybe occur some strange behavior.
Now i have a question:
The ```_state``` in this example has only one variable, but it may contain other variables. Example: a  email validator or a request in an API that are asynchronous.
In this case, would will be good pratice to create two controllers with broadcast, each one responsible for a state. The first being synchronous and the second asynchronous?
Or there is a possibility to use asynchronous operations in a synchronous broadcast?

Comment: I tested the asynchronous operations in a synchronous broadcast, but an error occured that async operators were called more than once, even when adding the distinct.